# how listen api changes in adapter MVVM

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm, android-mvvm

I want to listen to the Likes of each post from database so I wrote code to listen to the database in my adapter. How can do it with MVVM? Because in MVVM I cant write logic with view, so how do it with viewModel?

listen code in adapter

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(postModel.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        holder.tvLike.setText(String.valueOf(snapshot.getChildrenCount()));
   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `ViewModel` for that, tie & expose a `LiveData` or a `Flow`, observe & update the view in `Activity`.

Comment: i bass post id to adapter and in adapter listen with post id about likes and if i like or no how can i do that in activity and link that with adapter or is there any way to use viewModel in adapter??(i maked code about check if i liked or no and get num of posts)

Comment: The MVVM works heavily on the Observer Pattern. If you are working with Android for example, LiveData is commonly used. The way things works, you will have View observing changes in the ViewModel, the ViewModel listening to changes in the Model modified by your Repository. This provides flexibility because your View can interact with multiple ViewModels and your ViewModels can interact with multiple Models/Repositories. Your View should be dumb as a door knob. Your ViewModel should take care of the logic related with the View, and your Model/Repository should do extraction and processing.

Comment: I think repository is single source so the best is create one repository only.... Yeah i know that but how to accses viewmodel in adapter

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, then this article will help, [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: Yeah I am understand kotlin but i this that's not i need

Comment: I think i want some thing like observe livedata in adapter